# Riddle. Respond ASAP

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Not all glitters are gold, or so they say.
But I, I have a mind that seems to disagree.
I will break down the world to pay.
I will take up the mantle of belief.
Matter or not, it’s a matter of thy.
No matter is destroyed, is the matter at time.
All glitters are gold,
once it is I that's ahold.

What am I?

Comment: I edited/formatted your post to make it more "poemy." If this is contrary to your intentions in any way, please accept my apologies and [roll-back the changes here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/74917/revisions). Welcome to Puzzling.SE!

Comment: I turned an Edit from the OP into this comment: Rot13(Gunaxf sbe nafjrevat, ohg gur nafjre jnf nccneragyl nypurzl.)

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> King Midas?  A figure from myth who turned all that he touched into gold, explaining *All glitters are gold, once it is I that's ahold*, and somewhat explaining away the rest by that same logic:

Not all glitters are gold, or so they say.
 But I, I have a mind that seems to disagree.

> To you, what isn't gold, is as good as, so long as you can lay your hands on it.

I will break down the world to pay.
 I will take up the mantle of belief.

> You can literally pay for stuff by picking up e.g. bits of rock

Matter or not, it’s a matter of thy.
 No matter is destroyed, is the matter at time.

> You don't destroy matter but you convert it alche-m-agically to gold.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

> **cryptocurrency?**

Explanation (partial):

Not all glitters are gold, or so they say.
But I, I have a mind that seems to disagree.

> Maybe the reference to the widespread analogy between crypocurrencies and gold?

I will break down the world to pay.

> To pay with cryptocurrency, you need to generate (mine) some amount of it, but the energy consumption for it is constantly growing, which can in extreme cases "break down the world"

I will take up the mantle of belief.

> Many cryptocurrency implementations use proof-based techniques (i.e. no pure belief)

Matter or not, it’s a matter of thy.

> Cryptocurrency usually has no material form

No matter is destroyed, is the matter at time.

> Cryptocurrencies are blockchain-based and store all transaction history (i.e. no "matter" for the any given time is destroyed)

Also:

> *Respond ASAP* can mean that while mining, you actually must do some work ASAP, otherwise you will lose the reward for it (if somebody else does it before you).

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> Oil/Gasoline? Gasoline is a more intended answer.

Not all glitters are gold, or so they say.
But I, I have a mind that seems to disagree.

> Gasoline glitters as it has almost the same hue as gold

I will break down the world to pay.
I will take up the mantle of belief.

> Dig it up or drill down the earth to find it and refine it with machines to create gasoline

Matter or not, it’s a matter of thy.
No matter is destroyed, is the matter at time.

> It takes centuries for crude to develop

All glitters are gold,
once it is I that's ahold.

> Not sure but it makes the owner of the oil wealthy? I suppose